# How can I create text that lists its own physical dimensions?

Tags: positioning, calculations

In a similar vein to XKCD 688, I am trying to make a latex document that textually describes its own content:

[image: XKCD 688]

In particular, I want to be able to have the text list its own physical dimensions. For example:

> This line is 5.812 inches wide, and has a baseline 4.588 inches from the top of the page.

I understand that this is generally not possible because the dimensions may depend recursively on the text itself, and may not even converge at all.

However, if all the dimensions are listed using a fixed number of equal-width digits, the dimension values would not have any effect on the layout, making it at least in principle possible.

How can I create text that lists its own physical dimensions?

Comment: This question is a bit vague. If you specify which characteristics of words, lines etc you want to refer to, and in which way you want to refer to them, it may be done. You can add a `\tikzmark` to  a word and then read out its y coordinate to determine the distance from the top of the page. Or you can install a line counter to print the number of lines since the beginning of the document, etc.

Answer (score 4):

At least for a portion of text, you can store it in a box and access the geometrical properties of the box.

To remember the properties between tex runs and make it available at the time the box is defined, you can misuse the `totcount` package.

And last but not least, `\usepackage{printlen}` is a convenient way to print the values in your favourite unit.

The below example needs 3 runs to converge.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{printlen}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{mywidth}
\newtotcounter{myheight}

\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{\parbox{\textwidth}{This line is \uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\totvalue{mywidth}} wide, and has a height of \uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\totvalue{myheight}} and the line needs to be longer.}}

\usebox{\mybox}

\setcounter{mywidth}{\wd\mybox}
\setcounter{myheight}{\ht\mybox}
\addtocounter{myheight}{\dp\mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is clever!!!!! (+1)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm not sure storing a length in a counter is clever, maybe "reckless" is a better term.

Comment: It's possible, but not recommended. I would use a `zref` approach rather

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Can you please add an answer? I am curious to see the `zref` approach!

Comment: I have to write it yet :D

Comment: I think, you have forgotten the `\dp\mybox`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could be :)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, that was the problem. Thanks for spotting it! I now can confirm your 7.34 mm.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `zref` solution, which requires only two runs, but it has the current disadvantage, that the boxname is fixed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[user]{zref}
\usepackage{xprintlen}

\newsavebox{\mybox}%


\makeatletter
% Define some properties to store
\zref@newprop{width}{\the\wd\mybox}% This is a little bit unfortunate
\zref@newprop{height}{\the\dimexpr\ht\mybox+\dp\mybox}
% Add the properties to the main list
\zref@addprops{main}{width,height}

% Define two expandable properties extraction commands. 
\newcommand{\extractwidth}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{0pt}{%
    \zref@extract{#1}{width}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\extractheight}[1]{%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{#1}{0pt}{%
    \zref@extract{#1}{height}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\savebox{\mybox}{\parbox{\textwidth}{This line is \printlen{\extractwidth{boxlabel}} wide, and has a height of \printlen{\extractheight{boxlabel}} and the line needs to be longer.}}\zlabel{boxlabel}

\usebox{\mybox}


\savebox{\mybox}{\rule{10cm}{5cm}}\zlabel{rulelabel}

\usebox{\mybox}

\printlen{\extractwidth{rulelabel}} and \printlen{\extractheight{rulelabel}}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting - you're getting a different height. But it works for your rule, so I guess I have to go and debug my code.

Comment: @samcarter: I just used a ruler and measured the total height -- it's about 7mm, so in this case, the `\dp` should be added