# How to remember a length across compilations

Tags: auxiliary-files, totcount

I'm trying to save a length in the `.aux` file, so that it is remembered in the following compilation.

In other words, I'm looking for something like the [totcount](http://ctan.org/pkg/totcount) package, but which works for lengths.

More generally, is there a higher-level mechanism to save values across compilations? Tikz's `[remember picture]` is great and easy to use, while `\protected@write\@auxout` feels particularly low-level requires me to mess around with `\protected`, think about when the file is loaded etc.

Here is my non-working attempt so far.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\newlength\mylen
\mylen=0pt% Default value

\def\reloadmylen#1{\mylen=#1}

\def\changelen#1{
  \mylen=#1
  \protected@write\@auxout{}{\protect\reloadmylen{\the\mylen}}
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}

\the\mylen% Should print 20pt, but prints 0.0pt.

\changelen{10pt}
\changelen{20pt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Surprisingly `totcount` also works for lenghts

Comment: @samcarter How exactly do you leverage that feature? It's not documented, it seems, and there's no `\newtotlength` command.

Comment: see my answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353694/how-can-i-create-text-that-lists-its-own-physical-dimensions/353705#353705 -> just store it in a counter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\protected@write` is used if one wants to write the current value of a macro at the time of page-shipout to an external file.

In the OP's case, the dimen value after use of `\changelen` shall be stored in `\@auxout` (`\jobname.aux`). This can be done immediately and doesn't need to be delayed further, since the last value written out by `\changelen` is what counts when `\jobname.aux` is re-read during the second LaTeX run. That is why `\protected@write` is not the best choice here, but `\immediate\write` should be preferred.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\mylen
\mylen=0pt% Default value

\makeatletter    
% persistently sets length register
\def\changelen#1#2{%
  \global#1=#2%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\global#1=\the#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\the\mylen% Prints 20pt after the second run.

\changelen{\mylen}{10pt}
%\changelen{\mylen}{20pt}
\newlength\otherlen\otherlen=20pt
\changelen{\mylen}{\otherlen} % also works (can be used like `\setlength')

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good point. However, that's particularly low-level. `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` are particularly hard to get right, aside from the trivial single command and single argument cases.

Comment: Maybe it is also a good idea, for `\changelen` to accept the name of a length register to make it more versatile. See edit.

Comment: @Georges : Hopefully it is not too 'low-level' anymore.

Answer (score 10):

`\def\reloadmylen#1{\global\mylen=#1}`

Comment: (I wonder when the system flags this as low quality `:-)`)

Comment: Well, that was anticlimatic :) . Thanks! I'll wait a bit if someone suggests a better overall approach (my code is pretty verbose for what should be \newrememberedlength{\mylen}{0pt}).

Comment: Congrats on passing the 35K rep mark!!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the precision you need, you can simply use the `totcount` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{printlen}

\usepackage{totcount}
\newtotcounter{mylenght}


\begin{document}

\uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\totvalue{mylenght}}

\newlength\mylen
\setlength{\mylen}{4.9999999mm}

\setcounter{mylenght}{\mylen}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems hard to get the value back into a length, however (i.e. using it, not printing it). All variations on `\newlength\reloadedlen\expandafter\reloadedlen{\printlength{\totvalue{mylength}}}` which I tried seemed to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `totcount` with *no* approximation, using the fact that a length is coerced to an integer if we pass it as the value for a counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}

% a `total' counter for saving the value of \mylen
\newtotcounter{savedlength}

% allocate the length    
\newlength\mylen
% set it at begin document (using the last value in the previous run)
% the value had been coerced to an integer, that is, the length in scaled points
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\mylen}{\totvalue{savedlength}sp}}

% \changelen sets the value of \mylen, but also stores it in the counter
\newcommand\changelen[1]{%
  \setlength{\mylen}{#1}%
  \setcounter{savedlength}{\mylen}%
}

\begin{document}

\the\mylen

\changelen{10pt}

\the\mylen

\changelen{20pt}

\the\mylen

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note however that doing `\changelen` in a group will save the value; but you can of course say `\setlength` when you want to set a temporary value.