# Make code retrieve a dimensional value from later on in the code?

Tags: dimensions

Suppose that I have a dimension (call it `\shape`) whose value is to change locally several times throughout a piece of code. Suppose also that I have defined a command (called `\shifter` in the code that follows) that effects these changes. Then, is it possible to use, at the *beginning* of the code, the *final* value that `\shape` will take on? For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % Cancel automatic indentation

\newdimen\shape % Let there be the dimension \shape
\setlength{\shape}{0pt} % Let \shape start at 0pt
\newdimen\shapecompare % Let there be the dimension \shapecompare

\newcommand{\shifter}[1]{% If \shape is less than the width of the input of \shifter, then make \shape equal to the width of the input. Otherwise, do nothing.
\settowidth\shapecompare{#1}%
\ifdimless{\shape}{\shapecompare}%
{\setlength{\shape}{\shapecompare}}%
{}%
}%

\begin{document}

% At this moment (namely, the very beginning of the document), I would like to make use of whatever value \shape will end up at by the end of the code (namely, by the end, \shape = the width of the words ``Yes, sir, I will be there.'').

\hspace{\shape}Hello

\shifter{Hello}

\hspace{\shape}Hello

Hello

\shifter{Yes, sir, I will be there.}

\hspace{\shape}Hello

Yes, sir, I will be there.

\end{document}
```

Note: Stephen's answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55432/277990) to the question [How to retrieve a value which is set later on in the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55365/277990) seems like it could be relevant to my situation, but when I tried to replace its use of `\setvalue` and `\getvalue` into the corresponding terms in my situation, I couldn't get it to work --- and on top of that I'm not sure how the stuff about `.aux` works.

Comment: you need to write it to the aux and use it on the next run

Comment: So, you will need to learn how *aux works. Keep in mind that you should code the *aux in a way that does not crash the following compile, if you delete the *aux file. In other words, do not unconditionally try to read a value that you previously wrote to *aux, but first test whether such a value exists.

Comment: maybe have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355978/how-to-remember-a-length-across-compilations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write the setting in the `.aux` file, which is read in the next LaTeX run. Here you need `\global` settings, because the `.aux` file is read in a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newdimen\shape
\global\shape=0pt
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\write\@auxout{\global\shape=\the\shape}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\shifter}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%
  \ifdim\shape<\dimen0
    \global\shape=\dimen0
  \fi
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\hspace{\shape}Hello

\shifter{Tyrannosaurus}

\hspace{\shape}Hello

Tyrannosaurus % check the space

\end{document}
```

#### First run

[image]

#### Second run

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to cordon off different parts of a document so that several different final values of \shape can be established locally? (I am designing a template for a certain style of mathematical proof, and I want the rightmost column of a given proof to have its width equal to a *local* value of \shape.) I tried `\begingroup <proof> \endgroup`, but I couldn't get that to work --- I presume because `\global` overwrites the value of \shape everywhere. (I'm sorry I didn't say as much before. I didn't realize that I would need this extra condition to hold.)

Comment: @NoahJ Sorry, but the comment is too generic to be helpful. Please, open a new question with all the details.

Comment: New question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/694481/277990

Comment: `\immediate` would be safer I think, not sure a `\write` there is guaranteed to be shipped out

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I take your word for it.